# Clicking an element inside element handle

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

How can an element inside of existing handle be clicked?

Considering that there's a reference to foo handle:

```
const fooHandle = await page.$('.foo');
```

Currently foo selector is repeated:

```
page.click('.foo .bar');
```

I'd like to select `.bar` based on `fooHandle` reference instead of repeating `.foo` selector. In other places obtaining a handle with nested elements involves more complex checks that cannot be done with simple selector.

I'm using Playwright but I assume the solution is the same as for Puppeteer due to API similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Playwright, `$` and `$$` methods are available on [ElementHandle objects](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-query-selector) too:

> `elementHandle.$(selector)`
>
> `selector <string>` - A selector to query for.
>
> `returns: <Promise<null|ElementHandle>>`
>
> *The method finds an element matching the
> specified selector **in the ElementHandle's subtree**. [...]
> If no elements match the selector, returns null.*

So your code can be organized like this:

```
const fooHandle = await page.$('.foo');
const barHandle = await fooHandle.$('.bar');
await barHandle.click();
```